# How to Improve voice quality using "Speex"

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, adobe-media-server

I'm working on a live video streaming project and struggling with EXTRA NOISE coming from microphone. 
I am using speex Codec, and here the setting which i have used.

```
microphone = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
microphone.codec ="speex";

microphone.enableVAD = true;
microphone.setLoopBack(false);
microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
microphone.setSilenceLevel(0);
microphone.rate=44;
microphone.gain=1;
microphone.encodeQuality = 6;
microphone.

var micOption:MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = new MicrophoneEnhancedOptions();
micOption.mode = MicrophoneEnhancedMode.FULL_DUPLEX;
micOption.echoPath = 256;
micOption.autoGain = true;
micOption.nonLinearProcessing = true;


microphone.enhancedOptions = micOption;
```

Where should I make changes, and why ??

Comment: @gPeart Please do not use suggested edits to provide commentary or make semantic changes to code such as you did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28941920/2). Instead, add a comment.

Comment: @Radiodef, very good point. Roger that.